# Retornar valor no input noUiSlider

Tags: jquery

Preciso inserir em um formulário uma faixa de preços, estou utilizando o noUiSlider [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) com Jquery, esta funcionando, porem não consigo pegar os valores escolhidos, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

[Exemplo](http://upcomunicacaovisual.com.br/clientes/barrocamotos.com.br/teste.php)

```
 $("#slider-start").noUiSlider({
        start: [1000, 30000],
        range: {
            'min': [0],
            'max': [30000]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Há um exemplo na documentação do plugin de como capturar o valor
https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/

```
alert( slider.noUiSlider.get() );
```

Comment: Meu problema esta ai, não estou conseguindo achar a solução para passar os valores automaticamente  para o input text

Comment: Mostre mais detalhe do seu código, pois no site do plugin tem um exemplo que passa valores para o input na secção: Using HTML5 input elements

https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-html5

Comment: Vou postar o codigo com os JS completos acima, tem um link de exemplo la

Comment: Tentei jogar o codigo mais não deu

Na minha pergunta tem o exemplo e e so ver o codigo fonte, ta tudo lá